# Вычисление текущей даты и времени из unix time

Tags: java

Как возможно вычислить текущую дату, не используя стандартных библиотек, т.е через `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Год удалось вычислить, а вот с месяцем, числом и временем печалька... Подскажите, кто знает. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: покажи как ты год вычислил? разве юзать Date() или GregorianCalendar() уже не модно?

Comment: Количество дней с 01.01.1970г. как раз просто. В сутках 24*3600*1000 миллисекунд. А вот сколько дней в году -- зависит от года. И сколько дней в месяце -- зависит от месяца (а для февраля -- ещё и от года).

Comment: Я где-то видел довольно простую формулу для года

Comment: @maxus, просто интересно, как запрограммирован GregorianCalendar ? 

Или есть веские причины не скачивать его код из сети ?

Comment: Gorets, avp, читайте внимательно условие!

Comment: @maxus, а чем по Вашему System.currentTimeMillis() и Date.getTime() существенно отличаются ? 

А [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) пример использования календаря.

Comment: avp, потому, что можно использовать только System.currentTimeMillis() по условию

Comment: Так просто ведь

   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
   calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

а дальше берете что надо из методов и полей calendar().

Или у Вас такое *учебное задание*, а Вы нам голову морочите ?

Тогда принимайте ответ @sercxjo и за клавиатуру.

Comment: Я просто спрашиваю вариант решения задачи, БЕЗ использования библиотек, если бы было так просто как Вы говорите, я бы не спрашивал, это и в доках много инфы.

Comment: Без библиотек звучит, типа это что то волшебное. Все можно писать без них, если ты можешь быстрее написать собраные в них методы... Мы предложили решение твое задачи и даже, если ты не используешь либу, там всеравно можно посмотреть как она работает и чтото скопировать себе

Comment: Посмотрите наконец формулы в википедии

Answer (score 1):

[В википедии есть формулы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Юлианская_дата)