# Как узнать разницу во времени

Tags: java, android

Как узнать разницу во времени, например у меня дана дата в секундах `(Unix время)` и мне нужно перевести текущее время в `(Unix)` и узнать разницу в секундах.
Как мне сделать это?

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить в вопрос больше информации. Разницу между чем и чем вы хотите узнать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисление текущей даты и времени из unix time](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120915/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-unix-time)

Comment: нет это не дубликат, совершенно не дубликат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date oldDate = new Date(1322018752992l); //старое время в миллисекундах
Date newDate = new Date(); //текущее время
long seconds = (newDate.getTime()-oldDate.getTime())/1000; //возвращаем в секундах разницу
```

Comment: отлично newDate.getTime()

Answer (score 1):

Текущее время можно получить с помощью `System.currentTimeMillis()` - получите в милисекундах. Потом просто на 1000 поделить и будет в секундах.

Answer (score 1):

Если я корректно понял - нужна разница в секундах между текущим временем и заданным в виде unix epoch(секунды прошедшие с 01.01.1970)
Можно использовать следующий код:

```
Long date = new Date(12321413l).getTime(); // заданная дата в Unix-epoch в мс
Long currentDate =  new Date().getTime(); // текущая дата в Unix-epoch в мс

Long result = (currentDate - date)/1000; //разница в секундах между текущим временем и заданным

System.out.println(result);
```